# VueJS and UTF-8 encoding issue: Correctly formatting user copy and pasted text

Tags: vuejs2, formatting

I am using a data api that is returning text like so (from an archaic database):

```
Iâ€™m attaching a couple of our â€œquick lookâ€? cards covering the process
```

Notice the `â€™` symbols in the text. It appears that perhaps the user had copy and pasted text from an email message (outlook) or Microsoft Word and it appears to be a replacement for a comma or apostrophe (or who knows what else)?

Looks like this is what needs to be replaced:

```
[{broken: 'â€“',    fixed: "—"}
 {broken: "â€”",    fixed: "–"}
 {broken: "â€˜",    fixed: "‘"}
 {broken: "â€™",    fixed: "’"}
 {broken: "â€œ",    fixed: "“"}
 {broken: "â€", fixed: "”"}, ...]
```

Is there something I can do on the front end to replace those symbols with the correct character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an encoding problem and is [described here](https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html) and is, as you also described, reduced to a few characters:

> The following characters fail, while other characters display
> correctly:
>
> `€ ‚ ƒ „ … † ‡ ˆ ‰ Š ‹ Œ Ž ‘ ’ “ ” • – — ˜ ™ š › œ ž Ÿ`.

There is also a [debug sheet](https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) to find out the expected characters in UTF-8.

So maybe a solution would be to replace these list of characters after getting the data from the API or handling it with a function.

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mgfxv3r/) with replaces that chars with the function `replaceEncodingErrorCharsInString()` :

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    encodingReplacement: [
    {
        broken: 'â€“',
        fixed: "—"
        }, 
    {
      broken: "â€”",
      fixed: "–"
    }, {
      broken: "â€˜",
      fixed: "‘"
    }, {
      broken: "â€™",
      fixed: "’"
    }, {
      broken: "â€œ",
      fixed: "“"
    }, {
      broken: "â€",
      fixed: "”"
    }],
    exampleTexts: [
      "This is â€“ !",
      "This is â€” !",
      "This is â€˜ !",
      "This is â€™ !",
      "This is â€œ !",
      "This is â€“ !"
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    replaceEncodingErrorCharsInString: function(text){
        for(let i=0; i < this.encodingReplacement.length; i++) {
        // string contains "broken" chars
        if(text.includes(this.encodingReplacement[i].broken)) {
            text = text.replace(this.encodingReplacement[i].broken, this.encodingReplacement[i].fixed)
        }
      }
      // string is fine, just return it
        return text
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Awesome will give it a try and report back!

Comment: In the replaceEncodingErrorCharsInString function, inside the if, it should update "text" instead of returning, like: text = text.replace(...) and return later. Really useful example still

Comment: You are totally right @ivanf , i updated that part and the fiddle as well. Thx